# Interating an object inside the List Object

Tags: java, android

```
private List<Pair<String, List<ClassName>>> documents = 
                    new ArrayList<Pair<String, List<ClassName>>>();
```

I am trying to iterate the current List Object, so that i can get the `ClassName.getId();`. My ClassName Object has a getId(), which i need to disply. How would i `iterate` such that `i can get the Id.`

I was looking at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html, but could not get anything out of it.

Comment: Iterate over `documents` to get `Pair` , from `Pair` get the list of `ClassName` and iterate over that list to get the Id !!

Comment: As you have a list of pairs, you need to iterate that list. Then, each Pair has a List you have to iterate, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want to do :

```
for(Pair<String, List<ClassName>> doc : documents ) {
    for(ClassName object : doc.second) {
        object.getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need this?

```
private List<Pair<String, List<ClassName>>> documents = 
                new ArrayList<Pair<String, List<ClassName>>>();

//...
for(Pair<String, List<ClassName>> pair : documents) {
    for(ClassName className : pair.second) {
        // do what you want with className
        className.getId();
        // blah blah blah
    }
}
```